# How can I use radio button for choosing gender in my ionic 3 angular app?

Tags: android, html, mobile, ionic3, angular6

I am new to angular and `ionic 3`. Now only I'm learning it.

Currently, I'm using the angular forms for getting the employee details and saving it in the database table.

It contains the following fields `firstname`,`lastname`,`gender`,`DOB`,`Departmnet`etc.

For gender currently, I'm using `modal drop-down box` which contains two values(Male and Female) & selecting it.

> I need to use **radio-button** for choosing it instead of the modal
>   drop-down.

**How can I implement it?**

Please, guide me. I've only a little knowledge in `HTML` and `CSS` too. Please currently need your help guys. An example link or tutorial is highly appreciated. I have already tried to implement the radio-buttons using `<ion-list>`, but it ends  up with alignment problems.

I have mentioned here whatever I've tried so far.

**employee-details.html:**

```
<ion-item no-lines>
<ion-icon class="iconstyle" name="md-contacts" item-start></ion-icon>
<ion-label floating color="primary">Gender</ion-label>
<ion-select class="mydate" formControlName="gender" [(ngModel)]="vm.gender" class="textcolor" value="gender">
<ion-option *ngFor="let item of genderlist" value="{{item.key}}">{{item.value}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
</ion-item>
<div class="error-message-emp" *ngIf="formemp.controls.gender.errors && (formemp.controls.gender.dirty || formemp.controls.gender.touched)">
<span *ngIf="formemp.controls.gender.errors?.required">Gender is required</span>
</div>
```

Here i have specified how I have taken the key values for gender in the array

employee-details.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import {EmployeeService} from '../../services/employee.service';
import {compareValidator} from '../../shared/directives/comparevalidator';
import { MessageService } from '../../services/message.service';
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

import { BroadCastService } from '../../services/broadcast.service';
import { isNullOrUndefined } from 'util';
import { Employee } from '../../models/employee';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * Generated class for the EmployeeDetailsPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-employee-details',
  templateUrl: 'employee-details.html',
  providers :[EmployeeService]
})
export class EmployeeDetailsPage {
  formemp: FormGroup;
  value: any;
  setdeptlist = [];
  emailpattern: string = "[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$";
  vm: Employee;



  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private employeeservice: EmployeeService, private message: MessageService,private platform: Platform,  public keyboard: Keyboard, public broadCastService: BroadCastService,) 
  {
    employeeservice.getdepartment().subscribe(res =>{
      console.log(res);
      if(!isNullOrUndefined(res)) {
        this.setdeptlist = res;

      }
    })
    this.vm = new Employee();

  }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.initializeValidators();
    }
    initializeValidators(){
      this.formemp = new FormGroup({
        firstname : new FormControl ('', [Validators.required]),
        lastname : new FormControl ('', [Validators.required]),
        dob: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        email: new FormControl('', {
          validators: [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.emailpattern)]
        }),
        gender: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        dept: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        others: new FormControl(null)

})
}
    resetForm(formGroup: FormGroup) {
      let control: AbstractControl = null;
      formGroup.reset();
      formGroup.markAsUntouched();
      Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach((name) => {
        control = formGroup.controls[name];
        control.setErrors(null);
      });
      this.initializeValidators();
    }
    submit(){
      if(this.formemp.valid){
        this.employeeservice.saveemployee(this.vm).subscribe(res=>{
          console.log(res);
          this.message.alert("Details has been added Successfully");
          this.resetForm(this.formemp);
        }, err => {
          this.message.alert(JSON.stringify(err.error));
      } )
      }
      else {
        this.validateFormControl(this.formemp);
      }
    }

departmentChange(event){
      debugger;
var check = event;
 var che =this.vm.dept;
 const others = this.formemp.get('others');
 if(this.vm.dept == "6" ){
   others.setValidators(Validators.required);

 }
 else{
   others.clearValidators();
 }
 others.updateValueAndValidity();

    }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad EmployeeDetailsPage');
  }

  moveFocus(event, nextElement, isLastControl) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      if (isLastControl && isLastControl === false)
          nextElement.setFocus();
      else if (isLastControl && isLastControl === true)
          this.submit();
  }
  }
  validateFormControl(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
      const control = formGroup.get(field);
      if (control instanceof FormControl) {
        control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
      } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
        this.validateFormControl(control);
      }
    });
  }
  genderlist = [
    { key: 1, value: "Male" },
    { key: 2, value: "Female" }
  ];
}
```

Here I have mentioned my service class for getting the gender value from `API`

**employee-service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { DataService } from "./data.service";


@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
    constructor(private dataservice: DataService) {

    }
    getgender(){
        return this.dataservice.getData('/api/lookup/getgender',true);
    }
}
```

Kindly help me guys. A million thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for your `<ion-select>` code it should look like this:

```js
<ion-item no-lines>
        <ion-icon class="iconstyle" name="md-contacts" item-start></ion-icon>
        <ion-label floating color="primary">Gender</ion-label>
        <ion-select class="mydate" formControlName="gender" [(ngModel)]="gender" class="textcolor" value="gender">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let item of genderlist" value="{{item.key}}">{{item.value}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

As for your form controls on the bottom in your div and span statements, You may need to update your question with more of your `employee-details.ts` code. I commented out those two statements and the select worked just fine.

Comment: ., I will update with my full employee-details.ts code, can you help me to implement radio-button for gender. I will edit the post with my whole ts code

Comment: I have posted my full employee-details.ts code. Pls help me friend. I am currently using ion-select option for gender, but I need to use radio-button to implement the same functionality

Comment: So just to clarify you want to show the radio buttons on the screen and not as a select option?

Comment: Yes..exactly. I want radio buttons not select options

Comment: Perhaps this is what youre looking for? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/radio/RadioButton/

Comment: ., Actually I have tried all these stuffs and docs. It ended up with some alignmment issue and I also don't know how to bind the value from the service to the radio button.  I am expecting my layout as follows

Gender       .Male            .Female

The label should be on the left most corner with both male and female radio buttons aligned side by side. If needed I can also ready to post my full HTML code too as an edit of this post. Shall I ?

Comment: So it seems like your service isn't playing a part in any form field in particular as of right now. What is the purpose of your service?

Comment: This service will be giving me the value of the gender male and female as 1 and 2 with 1 as male and 2 as female and it is GET method

Comment: Okay, well I'm not seeing the getGender() function call in your employee-details.ts, and also if your GET request is pulling the array of male and female you shouldn't have to create an object array with the static data.

Comment: @ Stephen Romero,, we are using key value pair for this gender API., I will paste the response here that I have got from the browser :

<ArrayOfKeyValuePairOfintstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
<KeyValuePairOfintstring>
<key>1</key>
<value>Male</value>
</KeyValuePairOfintstring>
<KeyValuePairOfintstring>
<key>2</key>
<value>Female</value>
</KeyValuePairOfintstring>
</ArrayOfKeyValuePairOfintstring>

Comment: So you're saying that I don't want this part right?

 genderlist = [
    { key: 1, value: "Male" },
    { key: 2, value: "Female" }
  ];

Comment: Well since you're getting the values from your API you have to call the service or even just the value of the variable to retrieve the data and then you can utilize it in your form so you wouldn't need the static data. does that make sense?

Comment: I am sending the data from here only I just now commented that object array nd re-run the app., the drop down is empty now.,

Comment: Like I said, your getgender() function is not being called anywhere I can see so I don't believe its being initialized, unless theres code I'm not seeing